# Webservice development

Tags: web-services, standards

are there any standards for web service development?

Answer (score 2):

[REST-ful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) is a "standard" that we have tried to adopt for all our web services.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: @Preet: No it's not, it's a loose convention of practices, and long way from being a standard.

Comment: It is simple, and therefore used far more widely on the Internet. The enterprise solutions usually go with more complex ways of achieving same results :)

Comment: remember that REST is not the answer for All Web Services! there is time that REST is not the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

[SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_%28protocol%29), [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) and [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) are the primary W3C standards for web services development.

Answer (score 1):

Most web standards are provided by [W3C community](http://www.w3.org/). WSDL is the standard that descibes the services methods, binding, end points, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Web Services are all about interoperability so follow [WS-I Basic Profile](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1-2004-08-24.html), it has all the standard guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

As in like the SOAP standard for data transfer? Is that how you mean?

Comment: SOAP is not a standard for data transfer.